# Passing auto incremented id through multiple forms

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

Need advice on what is the best approach to get the auto incremented id to be the same on multiple forms.

Basically I am using VB .Net with SQL Server as the backend. I wrote a few stored procedures to insert data and then I am calling the stored procedures on the front end. I have 3 forms and once the first form is submitted it generates an autoID and then takes the user to 2nd form.

In the second form I have a separate insert stored procedure is there a way to grab the id that the first form generated and for it to be consistent. Or should I store it in a variable after they submit the form and then call it in the second form.

I read about the `@@Identity` but that only grabs the id within that session since I am submitting the first forms data then going to the second wouldn't that be a different session.

Thanks

Comment: Never use @@identity for this purpose, it is unreliable. Use scope_identity() or the output clause instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored proc could return the identity value (use the output clause or scope_identity() to get it) as an output variable that you would store as a variable in your application, then it would be available to use.  You would want to make sure to null out the varaible when the person moves to a differnt record and after allthe associated formas have inserted records, so that you don;t inadvertently use it at some other time.

You do not want to ever use @@identity for this as it is unreliable and can create massive data integrity issues as it will give you the wrong value if someone adds a trigger that inserts to another table with an identity.

Comment: What i attempted to do was add this line of code to my stored procedure SELECT id from mytable where id = @id But then i could not figure out how to get that to work on the front end as there is no id parameter to pass it. Are you saying i should just add id= @@scope_identity() to the stored procedure and it will know to grab it from mytable

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this is causing you problems might be an indicator that this isn't the best way to do it.   Perhaps instead, use a function on the DB to return the ID, and then set it in your .net code?

If you have an auto incremented ID, then it should only increment when a record is created.  Are your three forms creating three records?  Is that what you want?  If so, then an auto ID is definitely not the right way to go.

Comment: I have 3 different tables. The first form submits to one table which generates autoid. The second form submits to second table here is where i want the autoid that was generated in the first table to follow and add it to the second table. But the second form is a completely new form sorry if im not explaining this clearly

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your over thinking this?

> I read about the @@Identity but that only grabs the id within that session since I am submitting the **first forms data** then going to the second wouldn't that be a different session.

Don't you want the key that was generated by the entries made on the first form?

> In the second form I have a separate insert stored procedure is there a way to **grab the id that the first form generated** and for it to be consistent. Or should I store it in a variable after they submit the form and then call it in the second form.

Comment: You are probably right I am still learning vb and i find myself over thinking a lot of stuff more because i dont completely grasp what i am doing as of yet but i am reading and trying to understand what i am doing so i can become a better programming. Just the more i read sometimes the things i read confuse me more

Comment: I do want to get the key generated by the first form except if i put in my stored procedure @id = scope_identity() i am not sure how in vb to pass the id it generated to the second form. I am reading about global variables is that the right way to go? To create a global variable and pass it to the second form when the user clicks the submit button

Comment: Sorry, don't know enough about VB to answer that question.  In C# there are meathods which you use to execute store procedures, which return a data table.  In you stored proc after the inserts say select @@identity. Then in C# You'd have something like result.rows[0][0].